# Java Windows 10 Error : 1601

Tags: windows-10, installation, java

I tried YouTube and other stuff but it didn't help it shows `error 1601` and my windows installer service not working pls help :( I first tried to register and restart windows installer server didn't work then its showed error

> ' msiexec ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Please help :( I tried java uninstaller tool and there was not java installed and I tried offline version of java

---

I did delete it and I dont know what system % path you talking about I have no Java installed it never installed I tried system reboot 2 times and I tried online Java install offline ( 32 & 64 both ) nothing worked!

Comment: Remove Java (Programs and Features); restart; Install the newest version (8.331)

Comment: Is your SYSTEM %PATH% environment variable messed-up or out-of-order?  Is another installer instance already running and pending termination?  Did you download a 64-bit installer for 32-bit Windows?  Have you tried a system reboot?

Comment: I never actually install @leeharvey1 I dont know what system % path you talking about I have no Java instralled it never instralled I tried system reboot 2 times and I tried online Java instrall offline ( 32 & 64 both ) nothing worked!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of troubleshooting this worked for me ([source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/java-error-1601/22520bd0-e623-478a-ac18-09e6a1fa9083)):

1. Boot into safe mode with networking
2. Use the [uninstall diag](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d) to uninstall any Java installations one at a time.
3. Reboot normally.
4. Install Java 64-bit.